# how to permanently stop jshint 'read only' warning/error?

Tags: javascript, jshint

I tried to find a solution but it seems I can't use any flag for this. If I declare a global variable initially null like this:

```
close = null;
```

I then get an error of 'read only'. It's useless in my case. How can I stop it?

Answer (score 3):

When you define globals for jshint, you have to also declare whether you allow re-assigning them or not.

```
/* global close:false */
```

or the equivalent of

```
"globals": { "close": false }
```

in your .jshintrc file will allow the close global to be used, but not to be reassigned.

```
/* global close:true */
```

will allow redefining, and `close = null` will not throw a jshint warning anymore.

Comment: Thank you. So, is 'close' a jshint reserved word? I understand your solution, but I can't understand why naming 'close' a variable should be not allowed

Comment: by the way: same problem with 'W020 bad option'

Comment: @Stratboy it is not a jshint reserved keyword, it's an attribute of browsers' global window object. (open your developer console and just write close) Elaborate on that bad option problem.